# Replace NAs with the next number that appears

Tags: r

For the data shown below, I need to replace the NAs in the "question" column with the next number that appears. For example, time 1544890711782 would be question 1 and time 1544890722157 would be question 2.

**Data**:

```
structure(list(participant = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), time = c(1544890711782, 1544890711809, 
1544890711834, 1544890711862, 1544890711887, 1544890711899, 1544890722157, 
1544890722182, 1544890722210, 1544890722236, 1544890722245), question = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L)), row.names = c(8470L, 8471L, 8472L, 8473L, 8474L, 27150L, 8852L, 8853L, 8854L, 8855L, 
27134L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using na.locf from package zoo:
(assuming you store you dataframe in an object called 'data')

```
library(zoo)
data$question <- na.locf(data$question, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
```

(fromLast set to T: so we look to first nonmissing value; na.rm set to F: so trailing NAs are not discarded)

Output:

```
      participant         time question
8470            x 1.544891e+12        1
8471            x 1.544891e+12        1
8472            x 1.544891e+12        1
8473            x 1.544891e+12        1
8474            x 1.544891e+12        1
27150           x 1.544891e+12        1
8852            x 1.544891e+12        2
8853            x 1.544891e+12        2
8854            x 1.544891e+12        2
8855            x 1.544891e+12        2
27134           x 1.544891e+12        2
```